# Animate and Hide table including borders

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to collapse and expand a table with jquery animate. I'm using div's inside td and setting it's height to 0. How can I hide the borders as well when the height is animated to 0.

```
$('.table').find('td').css('overflow','hidden')
$('.table').find('td').children('div').animate(
                                         {height: '0px',
                                              opacity: 0}, 500);
```

Also I'm unable to set the state to table to either collapsed or expanded

```
$tbl.data("data",state);   //Doesn't seem to change the data value.
```

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/SKxS3/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you should do:

- Put var `state` outside onclick handler, so it is a global variable
- Move hide animation lines to block where you are collapsing the table
- Create another animation to expand the table again
- Finally, if you want to hide all the table once your collapsing is done, you can add `$tbl.hide();` at the animation ending function.

[DEMO FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/k2Ua4/1/)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, to the first point I cannot have a variable because I can many tables within the page so global variable will not work out. Animation for expand doesn't seem to happen at all, i tried changing the timer value from 500 to something higher but still animation doesn't work properly.

Comment: Maybe you could use blind() effect instead? http://api.jqueryui.com/blind-effect/